# realizar distintas acciones cuando el valor es igual en Javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo que enviar un mensaje cuando el valor del total sea x, este total lo saco sumando el valor de unas variables, pero cuando dos sumas de esas variables dan el mismo resultado, solo me envía el ultimo mensaje. La cuestión es que yo quiero que me muestre un mensaje si el total es z+x, pero si el total es y+x+n me tiene que mostrar un mensaje distinto, no los dos, o uno o el otro. Pues segun el resultado lo tengo que enviar a una dirección url distinta. Os he puesto un pequeño ejemplo porque el código que tengo es extremadamente largo y con muchas variables y creo que con esta muestra ya es suficiente, pero si alguien necesita más datos solo tiene que pedirlos. Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
total = 6;

y=1;
x=2;
n=3;
z=4;

if (total==z+x){
alert('este total es cuatro + dos');

}else if (total== y+x+n){
alert('este total es uno + dos + tres');
```

}

Comment: Creo comprender tu problema, lo que yo haría es a tu condición agregarle cuántas sumas intervinieron para llegar al resultado, es decir si para llegar a 6 solo se usaron 2 variables (z+x) imprimes el primero, pero si en ese resultado se usaron 3 variables(y+x+n) se imprime el segundo, debes agregarle esta evaluación a tus condicionales, quedaria asi if(total==z+y && variables==2)...else if(total==y+x+n && variables>=3)...

Comment: Es una solución, pero como le hago esa condición, las pongo en un array y las cuento? Esto lo haria con un String, pero con variables... no se me ocurre nada. Tambien es verdad que llevo diez horas con el código y ya tengo las neuronas fritas.

Comment: @jbort no entiendo cuál es el problema. Con remover el `else` y usar simplemente dos `if` se muestran los dos mensajes.

Comment: No quiero mostrar los dos mensajes. Quiero mostrar un mensaje u otro, según sean las variables que se usen para llegar a ese resultado. Si llego a total seis, sumando dos artículos envío los datos a un formulario con esos dos artículos (z y x). Pero si llego a ese resultado sumando tres artículos, tengo que enviar a un formulario los datos de los tres artículos. No se si se entiende mejor.

Comment: ¿Uno u otro? Te cito "La cuestión es que yo quiero que me muestre un mensaje si el total es z+x y otro mensaje si el total es y+x+n". Creo que deberías explicar mejor tu problema. No queda claro.

Comment: Puede ser que no me haya explicado bien, ahora edito la pregunta.

Comment: Existen mas variables o solo tendrás esas 4 variables? Si solo son esas cuatro, puedes guardar esas variables en un array, luego recorres ese array y por cada iteración sumas en otra variable el resultado ademas tambien de ir guardando una variable contadora, al final evalúas tu condición junto con la variable iteradora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible deducir los sumandos a partir del total, osea que solo se pude comparar con el total esperado e imprimir que es lo que se usó para alcanzar ese total.

```js
const suma = (arr) => {

  const res = arr.reduce((p, c) => p + c);

  (res === 6) && console.log('El total resulta de la suma de: ', arr.join(" + "));

}

suma([4, 2]);

suma([1, 2, 3]);

suma([100, -94]);
```

Si los argumentos son valores restringidos a ciertas variables, eso sería solo otra comparación.